# プライベートIPとグローバルIPにおけるネットワーク部の意味が理解できない

Tags: network

## 概要

IPアドレスについて調べているのですが、調べた情報がグローバルIPなのかプライベートIPのものであるかの区別が難しく混乱しております。
以下に疑問点を纏めましたので、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

この件の理解が浅く、上手い質問が出来ないので申し訳ありません。

## 疑問点

### 唯一つしか無いネットワークにおけるネットワーク部

１つのルーターに４つのデバイスが接続されているネットワークを考えるとする。
この状況においてはネットワークは１つしか存在していない。
そしてネットワーク部が無くても、ルーター内で一意なプライベートIPを各デバイスに割り当てれば問題なくルーティングを行えるはず。
ならばこのプライベートネットワーク内にネットワーク部という概念がなぜ必要になるのか？

### 複数のネットワークを切り分けるためのネットワーク構成

上と同じネットワークの状況を考えるとする。
この状況においてネットワークを複数に分割し、ネットワーク部を機能させるには
どのようなネットワーク構成にすれば実現するのか？

### CIDR

CIDRとはプライベートIP、グローバルIPどちらについての概念なのか？（あるいは両方？）
もしグローバルIPにも当てはまるのであれば、グローバルIPのネットワーク部とは何を意味しているのか？

### グローバルIPのネットワーク部

グローバルIPは全世界に一意に定義される。
つまりネットワーク部という概念が無くてもルーティングは可能。
なぜあえてネットワーク部という考えが存在しているのか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ならばこのプライベートネットワーク内にネットワーク部という概念がなぜ必要になるのか？

ご指摘のように必要ありません。想定のネットワークにはそもそもルーターは必要なく、スイッチングハブで十分です。そしてスイッチングハブであればネットワーク部に限らずネットワーク設定を必要としていません。
他の装置がネットワーク部の設定を要求するのは、既存のネットワーク製品を流用していて、既存機能と整合をとるために過ぎません。

---

> CIDRとはプライベートIP、グローバルIPどちらについての概念なのか？

どちらでもありません。ネットワークの中か外かを判断する基準です。通信相手のネットワーク部と自分のネットワーク部が一致していれば、同一ネットワーク内であり、ルーターを介さず直接通信可能と判断します。ネットワーク部が一致しなければネットワーク外であり、ルーターを介して通信します。

上記の通りですので、プライベート／グローバルは関係ありません。

---

> ネットワーク部という概念が無くてもルーティングは可能。

論理の飛躍があります。アドレスが一意であることと、通信相手に物理的に到達可能であることは関係ありません。もちろん、世界中の全ての機器が全ての機器の通信を受信していれば（つまり全世界が最初の質問のネットワーク構成となっていれば）到達可能ですが、ネットワーク負荷的に実現不可能です。

現実世界では前述の通り、ネットワーク内であれば直接通信をし、ネットワーク外はルーターを介して通信をします。それぞれのネットワークに存在するルーター同士がどのように接続されているかについては、[EGP/IGPやBGPなどの解説](https://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/newsletter/No35/0800.html)を読むと理解できるかと思います。

---

ここまでの説明でお気づきかと思いますが、「ルーティング」という用語は、通信相手とどのような経路で通信を行うかの判断そのものを指してます。そしてその判断の初手はネットワーク部が一致するかどうかです。