# グローバルIPにはサブネットマスクは存在するのか？

Tags: network

## 経緯

プライベートIPについては、IPアドレスとサブネットマスクの情報の存在が確認できました。
しかしグローバルIPについては、単にIPアドレスについての情報しか確認することが出来ませんでした。

```
$ curl inet-ip.info
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

### 理解していること

- IPアドレスはネットワーク部とホスト部で構成されている。
- IPアドレスのどこまでがネットワーク部であるかは、サブネットマスクで表される。

## 疑問

- グローバルIPにはサブネットマスクの情報は存在しているのか？

  - 存在するのであれば、サブネットマスクの確認方法は？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[プライベートIPとグローバルIPにおけるネットワーク部の意味が理解できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/84158/4236)で

> 通信相手のネットワーク部と自分のネットワーク部が一致していれば、同一ネットワーク内であり、ルーターを介さず直接通信可能と判断します。

と説明しました。もう少し補足します。例えば、

- 自分のアドレス **192.0.2.5**

  - サブネットマスク255.255.255.240 (28bit)
  - デフォルトゲートウェイ 192.0.2.1
- 相手のアドレス **203.0.113.5**

で通信する際、

- 自分のネットワークアドレスは**192.0.2.0**

  - 自分のアドレス192.0.2.5と自分のサブネットマスク255.255.255.240のbit and
- 相手のネットワークアドレスは**203.0.113.0**

  - 相手のアドレス203.0.113.5と自分のサブネットマスク255.255.255.240のbit and

となり、両者のネットワーク部が一致していないと判断し、ルーター（デフォルトゲートウェイ）に送信します。この判断過程において、相手のサブネットマスクは必要ありません。
加えて、この説明からもわかると思いますが、この判断過程において、グローバルIP／プライベートIPの区別もありません。

Answer (score 2):

まず、すべてのIPアドレスのうち、大きく分けて2種類あります。

- プライベートネットワーク用に予約されたIPアドレスをプライベートIPアドレス
- それ以外をグローバルIPアドレス

これは、世界のみんなで守ることになっているルールであり、IPネットワークの技術として区別は必要なく、一緒です。（実際のところネットワーク機器のデフォルトで、プライベートIPアドレスの範囲は外に通信させない等のルールが入っていたりするので、あくまで机上の話）

グローバルIPアドレスにも、サブネットマスクはあります。（ネットワークアドレス部があると言ったほうが良いかも）

割り当てられるグローバルIPアドレスの範囲にもよりますが、小さいものではネットワークアドレス部が /30 (サブネットマスク 255.255.255.252)で割り当てられ、その中からゲートウェイのIPアドレスを指定されます。

巨大なグローバルIPアドレス空間を持つ組織は、その中で /24 ごとにネットワークを分割するなど、我々が見慣れたプライベートIPアドレスと同じことができます。

よく目にする例外として、PPPoEですとサブネットマスクが 255.255.255.255 でIPアドレスが割り振られます。

確認方法は・・・難しい。実際の機械に入るか、管理者にでも聞かないと分からない、と思います。

Answer (score 0):

グローバルIPのサブネットマスクは各プロバイダー等によって管理されています。
自由に設定することはできません。
例えばグローバルIPをプロバイダーから借りる場合、IPアドレスの数により、サブネットマスクが設定されます。